# LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection timed out AWS RDS POstgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using AWS RDS Postgresql.

When my website tries to connect to the database, it says:

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

However, I am able to connect to the database from the ec2 instance and via pgAdmin.

Elastic Beanstalk does not show any errors in the log. It runs my backend code which is Nodejs and with no errors. The health of EB is "Severe" tho, but it does not have any Html pages as it is for the backend only. So, I guess the health does not matter here as the log shows it runs on port 8080, and no errors are present.

The RDS Log shows the following:

```
database@database:[9935]:LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
```

I do not understand why my client cannot connect to the database. Password and master username and the endpoint are correct.

Parameters I use in Elastic Beanstalk for Postgres:

```
RDS_DB_NAME, RDS_HOSTNAME, RDS_PASSWORD, RDS_PORT, RDS_USERNAME
```

To connect from my local terminal and from EC2 instance I use:

```
psql --host=endpoint --port=5432 --username=username --password --dbname=database
```

Connection to Postgres: It works locally, before deploying the app.

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({

host     : process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
user     : process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
password : process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
port     : process.env.RDS_PORT,
database : process.env.RDS_DB_NAME
});
module.exports = pool;
pool.connect(function(err) {
if (err) {
    return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
}
console.log('Connected to the Postgres server.');
});
```

Then the elastic beanstalk log file shows me that it is connected:

```
web: Connected to the MySQL server.
```

Comment: Can you include how you tested the connection (e.g. what parameters did you provide [excluding password]) and how you're attempting to connect from your application (what parameters you're using in you application config/etc).

Comment: @melcher I edited the question and added the description.

Comment: How is your node.js server connecting to postgres? (e.g. what ORM, how is the connection configured?)

Comment: @melcher I added the connection to postgres